# GitHub Client Createing master and release Branches

Tags: git, github, branch, branching-and-merging, github-for-windows

I'm new to GitHub and Git. But got some experience over the last month. I use the Windows XP client.

What I would like to do is do all my dev in master, so all my notes, scratch work, psd files of the images are here. So lets say i went from commit "initial.rev0" to "initial.rev5"

Now .rev6 I want to release but in here I want to remove all the comments from my files. So I do that then create "release" branch and put .rev6 and call it "initial.rev6". The problem is here, ill explain in a second.

Then I switch back to master branch and continue my work with the files with all the debug stuff in tact. I do a commit here in master and it's now "initial.rev7". We don't see "initial.rev6" in master branch. Release branch does not have "initial.rev7" which is good.

So now on the release branch it now has all commits "initail.rev0" till "initial.rev5" thats the problem. How can I make it so release branch starts with commit "initial.rev6".

I thought to create "release" branch at start when i Make the repo but its having problems it says I need at least 1 commit before branching.

Thx

Comment: I'm sorry but from your explanations it's not pretty clear why you don't need commits 'rev0'...'rev5' in the release branch. Does 'rev6' contain the state (file tree, commit message etc) suitable for release? If it does, you don't need to make anything with the predecessor commits, they are the part of the history, not the part of the actual state.

Comment: Certainly, if you wish to completely tear 'rev6' off its parents, you can do that. But it this case further merging between `release` and `master` branches will be not as easy as when branches have common ancestors.

Comment: oh i dont plan to do any merging after that. the reason i want the release on seperate branch is because i strip out all the debug msessages and stuff, and i delete all the psd and other raw src files that are not needed in the compile.

Comment: im not sure if rev6 has file tree. i know it has commit message of me saying "i removed all debug and added screen shot and blah blah" stuff i stripped out from

Comment: Does rev6 has _any_ file ?

Comment: ah yep i delete all the extra stuff but leave the important stuff. so it has install.rdf, bootstrap.js and icon.png.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47574/discussion-between-user3159253-and-noit)

Comment: a sincere thank you!! i want to learn so much with github because im trying to createa bunch of templates to make it easy for new developers